# How to safely straighten 2569 Lego Antenna Whip 8H?

Tags: repair

I have one of those, in trans-neon green, that's slightly bent. I don't want to break it or make it opaque. Is there a way to make it straight again without risk? Preferably universal way, but way specific to [2569](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2569#T=P) piece would suffice.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a particular rare part, easily replaced with bricklink for a couple of cents, so I wouldn't worry about damaging it. If it's bent it's damaged anyway.

For standard lego made out of ABS the procedure is to submerge it in hot water (hot to the touch but not scalding or boiling) for about a minute and then straighten it with your fingers or pliers in cold water...

However, this is a transparent piece so made out of PC instead of ABS. The melting point of PC is is about 50 degrees Celsius higher. So I guess the hot water will need to be near boiling...